# Xcode: GDB and signal handlers

Tags: xcode, gdb, signals

I'm using signal handlers in an Objective-C application to catch fatal errors, as `SIGSEGV`, `SIGBUS` and the like.

When such an signal is raised, I'm writing a log file, with a backtrace and details about the error (I know I can have reentrancy issues, but that's not the point).

This way, I can know on the next launch that the application has crashed, and I can ask the user if he want to fill a bug report.

It works fine when I launch the app manually.

But when I run it from Xcode (with GDB), the signal handlers are not called.

I've try to set them with `signal` or `sigaction`, but there's no difference.

I've also checked with `info signals` that those signals are set to `pass`, meaning they should be passed to the application.

That's not a big deal, as I only got this problem when I'm debugging my application, but it will be very nice to have that working also with GDB.

Has anyone experienced and solved such a problem?

Comment: You might want to try to set these signals to nostop in gdb, so it is managed by your application.

Comment: I tried that before asking the question, but I guess I made a mistake because it did not work. I tried it again today, and it's working like a charm. You may want to fill an answer with this, so I can accept it. Thanks : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try to set these signals to nostop in gdb, so it is managed by your application.